# Data Filtering in NS Table in MAC OS Dev.

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a NSTable on a form with data rows, I have a button on the form and when I click on the button I call a delegate/method to filter the data and reloadData.

Filter with predicate works, returning the filtered array but the grid does not show the changed data

shown below is the method for the button-click

```
- (IBAction)filterOnClick(id)sender {
NSString *age = @"62";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Age >= ", age];
NSArray *arr = [arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingArrayPredicate:predicate];

[gridView reloadData];

}
```

note: arrayPDContent is the NSMutableArray which is used to load data, arr above may not ne needed.

show below is a part of the code to populate the NSMutableArray

```
NSString *sAge = [NSString stringWithUTFString:sqlite3_column ....];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:sAge, COLUMN_ID, nil];
[arrayPDContent addObject:dictionary];
```

Note: since i was unable to login from inside MAC OS i inputted part of the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using the following code as posted above by **Nate Chandler**

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [[arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]] count];
}
```

and

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)column row:(NSUInteger)row
{
    return [[[arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]] objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:COLUMN_ID];
}
```

it filter ok, but loop and the Colored ball keeps spinning on and on

can any one provide a easy to implement idea, short of rewriting the code as suggested by him towards the end on the answer

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayPDContent 
{
   .....
   ....
```

Comment: At the risk of being obvious, notice that you'll need to change `[arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]]` to `[self filteredArrayPDContent]` in your methods `-numberOfRowsInTableView:` and `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSArray` method `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` creates a new array containing only those objects in the receiver which pass the filter. You're using a local variable `arr` to hold that array, but it gets discarded (or at least becomes inaccessible) when it goes out of scope at the end of your `filterOnClick:` method. Presumably your data source methods still reference `arrayPDContent`, so your table shows the unfiltered array.

If you want to change the contents of a `NSMutableArray` so that it holds only those objects matching a filter, you want `filterUsingPredicate:` instead. (However, note that this discards anything else -- if you want to show the original data again after the user clears the filter, you'll need to store it somewhere else.)

You might consider using one ivar/property to store the "real" data, and another to store the filter results (created using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`); have the table data source methods reference the latter if a filter has been set.

Comment: **arr** was only for debugging purposes, i did mention this in the original posting. filtering on **age** is again for testing purposes, ultimately i will be filtering on a over 20 different fields and equations

Comment: @Jaggu The point is that the `NSArray` that you're using to populate the `NSTableView` is not getting filtered.  In `-filterOnClick:` you're calling `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` on `arrayPDContent` and expecting `arrayPDContent` to change.  `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` does not mutate the object its sent to; it returns a filtered array and leaves the original array unchanged.  As @rickster points out, sending `filterUsingPredicate:` to `arrayPDContent` will mutate `arrayPDContent`; as a result, when `gridView` reloads its data, the correctly filtered array will be used.

Comment: filtering is working ok, but it loops through thereby making the colored ball to keep spinning

Comment: **NOTE:** i am no longer using **arr** it was for debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

You've written

```
NSArray *arr = [arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingArrayPredicate:predicate];
```

Since `-filteredArrayUsingArrayPredicate:` is not a method on `NSMutableArray` and the only search results for the term "filteredArrayUsingArrayPredicate" are the two questions you've opened with the same content, I'm going to assume that this is a typo for `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

---

You're using `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` on your `NSMutableArray` `arrayPDContent` and you're expecting that this will mutate `arrayPDContent`.  This is not what [`-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a) does; this is a method on `NSArray` and has the same behavior on all `NSArray`s, including `NSMutableArray`s.  We can imagine its implementation is something like the following:

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableRes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id obj in self) {
        if ([predicate evalutateWithObject:obj]) {
            [mutableRes addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return [mutableRes copy];
}
```

In particular, this `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` does not mutate its target, even if that target is an instance of `NSMutableArray`.

An immediate solution to your problem would be to write

```
arrayPDContent = [[arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

in place of

```
NSArray *arr = [arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

---

This is not a good solution, though, since you're destroying data by doing this.  Any objects in `arrayPDContent` which are filtered out here are lost.

A better solution would be to store the predicate as a property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSPredicate *filter;
```

and change your implementations of [`-numberOfRowsInTableView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDataSource/numberOfRowsInTableView%3a) and [`-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDataSource/tableView%3aobjectValueForTableColumn%3arow%3a) to make use of the new property:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [[arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]] count];
}
```

and

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)column row:(NSUInteger)row
{
    return [[[arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]] objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:COLUMN_ID];
}
```

rather than

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [arrayPDContent count];
}
```

and

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)column row:(NSUInteger)row
{
    return [[arrayPDContent objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:COLUMN_ID];
}
```

---

This is not a very good solution either since the filtered array is being computed repeatedly.  A still better solution would be to cache the array, adding the property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *filteredArrayPDContent;
```

to your table view's delegate with the getter implementation

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayPDContent
{
    if (!_filteredArrayPDContent) {
        _filteredArrayPDContent = [arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]];
    }
    return _filteredArrayPDContent;
}
```

and setting `_filteredArrayPDContent` to `nil` whenever either `arrayPDContent` or `[self filter]` changes.

**Edit, Additional**:

To get you part of the way to setting `_filteredArrayPDContent` to `nil` whenever either `arrayPDContent` or `[self filter]` changes, you can add the method

```
- (void)resetFilteredArrayPDContent
{
    _filteredArrayPDContent = nil;
}
```

Since this method should be called from wherever you mutate `arrayPDContent` or change `[self filter]`, you should call this method in the following places:

`1.`  Within `-filterOnClick:`:

```
- (IBAction)filterOnClick(id)sender 
{
    NSString *age = @"62";
    [self setFilter:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Age >= ", age]];
    [self resetFilteredArrayPDContent];

    [gridView reloadData];
}
```

And `2.`  after populating `arrayPDContent`:

```
for (/*...*/) {
//...
    NSString *sAge = [NSString stringWithUTFString:sqlite3_column ....];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:sAge, COLUMN_ID, nil];
    [arrayPDContent addObject:dictionary];
//...
}
[self resetFilteredArrayPDContent];
```

You will need to call `-resetFilteredArrayPDContent` **(A)** whenever you set the value of `[self arrayPDContent]`, whether you set the instance variable directly or call the method [self setArrayPDContent:] (whether using the standard bracket notation or the new dot notation, `self.arrayPDContent = //...`) and **(B)** whenever you mutate `arrayPDContent` (via `-addObject:`, `-removeObject:`, `-filterUsingPredicate:`, or any other method on `NSMutableArray` which mutates the array).

**Edit Continued, Alternative**:

In place of `1.` above, you could instead alter the implementation of `-setFilter:`:

```
- (void)setFilter:(NSPredicate *)filter
{
    _filter = filter;
    [self resetFilteredArrayPDContent];
}
```

and be sure that you are calling `-setFilter:` (whether using bracket--`[self setFilter:filter]`--or dot--`self.filter = filter`--notation)  rather than setting the instance variable `_filter` directly in `-filterOnClick:` and wherever else `[self filter]` is changed.

In place of `2.` above, you could instead add the method

```
- (void)addArrayPDContentObject:(id)obj
{
    [arrayPDContent addObject:obj];
    [self resetFilteredArrayPDContent];
}
```

and call it when populating `arrayPDContent`:

```
for (/*...*/) {
//...
    NSString *sAge = [NSString stringWithUTFString:sqlite3_column ....];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:sAge, COLUMN_ID, nil];
    [self addArrayPDContentObject:dictionary];
//...
}
```

You would need to add similar methods for other sorts of mutations to `arrayPDContent`:

If inserting an object into `arrayPDContent` at a particular index, add

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)obj inArrayPDContentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [arrayPDContent insertObject:obj atIndex:index];
    [self resetFilteredArrayPDContent];
}
```

and call

```
[self insertObject:obj inArrayPDContentAtIndex:index];
```

rather than

```
[arrayPDContent insertObject:obj atIndex:index];
```

If removing an objects from `arrayPDContent` at a particular index

```
- (void)removeObjectFromArrayPDContentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [arrayPDContent removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [self resetFilteredArrayPDContent];
}
```

and call

```
[self removeObjectFromArrayPDContentAtIndex:index];
```

rather than

```
[arrayPDContent removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

Et cetera.  The naming conventions for these methods are found [here in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB).

**Edit, Additional Alternative**:

*The easiest but the worst* solution to the problem is to cache the previous versions of `arrayPDContent` and `filter` whenever computing `_filteredArrayPDContent` and checking the current version against the previous.  After adding the properties

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *oldArrayPDContent;
@property (nonatomic) NSPredicate *oldFilter;
```

change the implementation of `-filteredArrayPDContent`:

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayPDContent
{
    if (![[self oldArrayPDContent] isEqualToArray:arrayPDContent] 
        || ![[[self oldFilter] predicateFormat] isEqualToString:[[self filter] predicateFormat]]) {
        _filteredArrayPDContent = [arrayPDContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self filter]];
        [self setOldFilter:[self filter]];
        [self setOldArrayPDContent:[arrayPDContent copy]];
    }
    return _filteredArrayPDContent;
}
```

Note that `oldArrayPDContent` is set to be a *copy* of `arrayPDContent`.

I must reiterate: this may be the quickest drop-in replacement to improve performance, but it is not by any stretch of the imagination the most stylish.

---

A better solution still is to add an `NSArrayController` bound appropriately to your content array (note that the content array will need to be immutable for this to work--more accurately you won't be able to use `-addObject:` and other `NSMutableArray` methods without being careful) and binding your `NSTableView`'s rows to the `NSArrayController` appropriately.

Using this style, you'd simply call `-setFilterPredicate:` on the `NSArrayController` from `-filterOnClick:`.

Comment: using your **numberOfRowsInTableView...** method it does work but only just, as the colored ball just keeps spinning on and on.

Comment: I edited my answer, discussing a few different strategies for calculating `_filteredArrayPDContent` as infrequently as possible to improve performance and to stop that color ball in its tracks.